# Can wifi signal reception be improved by opening a door?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, interference

#### Use Case

A wifi user is in a different room than the router. The computer is having a hard time connecting and receiving the wifi signal.

### Engineering Question

Can the wifi signal from the router to the computer be improved by opening a door to the room where the computer is?

## Physics Question

> Please describe the electromagnetic field equations (including refractive indices of doors and walls) at play in the ***engineering question*** and whether you believe opening a door will affect these equations as it relates to field strength of the wifi signal at the computer. [See this article for inspiration](http://www.electronicproducts.com/Passive_Components/Antennas/Apartment_Wi_Fi_connectivity_mapped_using_physics_and_math.aspx).

http://www.electronicproducts.com/Passive_Components/Antennas/Apartment_Wi_Fi_connectivity_mapped_using_physics_and_math.aspx

#### Field Equations

(Differential Form)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Logically, it should. Wifi signal is a form of electromagnetic field. It is in a region of radio wave and cannot travel through solid object.

Comment: @TBBT: Okay. Then how do you explain the fact that when I close all the doors and windows to my room, say, I'm in a closet for example, I can still receive signal to my AM/FM radio?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I struggle to see what this has to do with physics.

Comment: @JohnRennie: Electromagnetic waves. Interference. Just because its about a real world practical application doesn't mean it doesn't involve physics.

Comment: For a wooden door, it might improve the signal slightly but I doubt you would even notice. WiFi signals are at a frequency that can penetrate pretty far through walls and doors. If it was a metal door directly between the device and router, you may notice a difference then.

Comment: From practical experience, I can say it definitely can. Even if the door is not roughly between the transmitter and the receiver.

Comment: experience: aluminum shutter on kitchen window, sitting at veranda about  two walls and 10 meters away ( in addition to shutter), no  WIFIsignal. Shutter opened, signal. A stainless steel bowl upside down on the table where the laptop sat  at a close by location, signal stronger and steadied. Think electromagnetic waves.

Comment: From a practical point of view, if you are having a hard time connecting your computer, or suffer from a slow connection, it is probably due to interferences with another WiFi antenna. Try connecting to your router (192.168.1.1 in a navigator) and changing the channel where it is emitting.

Answer (score 2):

If the WiFi antenna is emitting at 2.4 GHz, you could detect a slight improvement of the signal, but unless the door is solid and very thick, I doubt it will make much difference. If it is emitting at 5 GHz the improvement could be bigger, as the wavelength is reduced and the door appears "bigger" to the electromagnetic wave.

Finally, if your antenna uses the very new 802.11ad standard (though I doubt it), emitting at 60 GHz, you wouldn't want to put the emitter at a different room than your receiver.

In general, electromagnetic scattering is very dependent on the size of the scatterer relative to the wavelength $\lambda$ of the wave. In sub lambda scatterer sizes we are in the "**Rayleigh**" regime, where particles (or doors, or walls...) cause some dispersion but the waves are not much affected by them (consider the case of FM radio emission: the wavelengths are so large that the difference in reception inside/outside a building is not noticeable; the walls are *transparent* to the EM wave); in the lambda and sup-lambda regime, you need the full description of scattering from Maxwell's equations (as in "**Mie**" scattering) to get an accurate description of the process, but roughly speaking, particles (resp. doors, walls...) block (at least partially) the wave.

In WiFi emission you are stuck in a mesoscale with dimensions of the order of $\lambda$, so you can be in one regime or another depending on the frequency of emission.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the wifi signal from the router to the computer be improved by opening a door to the room where the computer is?

Not too much.

You can put your laptop 2 meters away from a door, exactly in front of it, while the router is on the other side of the door also 2 meters away. You will see that with the door opened or closed the signal received by your computer has about the same quality.